# Umbraco headless Node.js client cannot authenticate headless client

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have  been trying to implement the Node.js client for Umbraco headless. I have done the following:

- Set up Umbraco headless via my Umbraco cloud subscription
- Implemented a simple app in Vue.js
- Copied the example code from https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Umbraco-Cloud/Headless/Headless-Node-Client/
- when I run this code (via my localhost:8000) I get an authentication error
- https://{MyUmbracoCloudUrl}/umbraco/rest/oauth/token 400 (Bad Request).
- My config has the correct  domain name for the cloud instance and the correct user name an password.

I get a 400 response from  https://{MyDOMAIN}/umbraco/rest/oauth/token.

Does anyone have any ideas? I am not sure if this is a cors issue becuase I am trying to run this from my local host?

Cheers
L